# How to handle exceptions occured in the delegate target

Tags: c#, .net

I have a delegate which points to 3 different methods. These methods are added in its invocation list.

What is second method throws an exception??? I still need to execute the third method.

I think one alternative is below mentioned code

```
         public delegate void MethodHandler();
            A oa = new A();
            B ob = new B();
            C oc = new C();
            D od = new D();


            MethodHandler M = oa.TestM;
            M += ob.TestM;
            M += oc.TestM;
            M += od.TestM;

            foreach (Delegate item in M.GetInvocationList())
            {
                try
                {
                    item.DynamicInvoke(null);
                }
                catch
                {
                }

            }
```

Is there any other alternative to avoid this?

Comment: You should not be using `DynamicInvoke`, just cast the `Delegate` to what ever type it is, and call it like a method.

Comment: @leppie- any specific reason behind not using DynamicInvoke?

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to be able to "avoid" this in the sense of *not* using a `try`/`catch` pattern to ensure your code proceeds past a delegate that threw an exception.

Nothing's stopping you from writing your own class to wrap this functionality, though -- to mitigate the potential proliferation of this exact code everywhere you're using your `M` delegate.

By the way, I believe you can change this line:

```
item.DynamicInvoke(null);
```

to this (to avoid the `DynamicInvoke`):

```
MethodHandler handler = (MethodHandler)item;
handler.Invoke();
```

Comment: you should just call `handler()`  ;P

Comment: @leppie: It's the same thing. Some people prefer to explicitly include the `Invoke` call. I don't really have a preference, but I thought it'd be clearer to the OP as a direct replacement for the `DynamicInvoke` call.